# How to fix: 'NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined' in Pyspark foreach setup

Tags: python, pyspark, foreach, spark-structured-streaming, pydantic

I'm using Pydantic together with a `foreach` writer in Pyspark with structured streaming to validate incoming events. One of the fields of the incoming events is `timestamp`. Pydantic is able to handle datetime values according to their [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#datetime-types). I know how to import and use the datetime library but in this construction it gives me this error:

> NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Maybe this is because the Pyspark foreach function works with pickled objects?

See my (simplified) main program:

```
for_each_stream = my_dataframe \
    .do_some_parsing() \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(**trigger) \
    .foreach(MetricsParser())

for_each_stream.start()
```

The MetricsParser class used in the foreach setup:

```
import datetime

class MetricsParser:
    """Parse Metrics in foreach setup"""
    def process(self, row):
        class Metricbeat(BaseModel):
            """Base Pydantic class"""
            timestamp: datetime.datetime
            uuid: str
            metric: str
            value: int
        row_dict = row.asDict()
        result = Metricbeat(**row_dict)
        send_result_to_external_source(result)
```

Whenever I change the expected type of `timestamp` to `str` everything works fine but if I do it like in the example I'm getting the error stated in the beginning of this post. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't define a class within a function within another class

Comment: Would you try to move `import datetime` into `def process`?

Comment: @pltc That didn't work either unfortunately. Same error as before (in the question)